# Add 1 colum of mysql result to the result of another mysql result

Tags: php, mysql

At the moment I have 2 different mysql queries:

Query 1

```
SELECT monthname( calendar.datefield ) AS date,
    year(calendar.datefield) as year, calendar.datefield, COUNT(all_griefs_tbl.actioned_status ) AS total_griefs,
    all_griefs_tbl.actioned_status, all_griefs_tbl.game
FROM all_griefs_tbl 
RIGHT JOIN calendar 
  ON ( DATE(all_griefs_tbl.actioned_date ) = calendar.datefield )
    AND all_griefs_tbl.actioned_status = 'accepted'
WHERE calendar.datefield
  BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -12 MONTH)  AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY year( calendar.datefield ) DESC , month( calendar.datefield ) DESC
```

Query 2

```
SELECT monthname( calendar.datefield ) AS date, 
    year(calendar.datefield ) AS year, calendar.datefield,
    COUNT(all_griefs_tbl.actioned_status ) AS total_submitted,
    all_griefs_tbl.actioned_status, all_griefs_tbl.game 
FROM all_griefs_tbl 
RIGHT JOIN calendar 
  ON ( DATE( all_griefs_tbl.date ) = calendar.datefield ) 
WHERE calendar.datefield BETWEEN DATE_ADD( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL -12 MONTH ) AND CURDATE( ) 
GROUP BY year( calendar.datefield ) DESC , month( calendar.datefield ) DESC
```

Now the difference between these is in query 1 I'm counting the number of accepted griefs per month and in query 2 I'm counting the number of records submitted per month - counting different columns

What I want to do it either a) get this into a single query or b) be able to merge the results into 1 table.

I want the output to be as follow:

```
    Month         Year          Total Griefs  Total Submitted
    ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  
    April         2012          14            2      
    March         2012          0             8
    February      2012          0             6
    January       2012          0             13
    December      2011          0             7
    November      2011          0             10
    October       2011          0             0
    September     2011          0             0
    August        2011          0             6
    July          2011          0             3
    June          2011          0             2
    May           2011          0             0
    April         2011          0             0
```

Is this possible, or am I barking up the wrong tree entirely?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in one query:

```
SELECT 
    monthname( calendar.datefield ) AS date,
    year(calendar.datefield) as year, 
    calendar.datefield,
    SUM(IF(all_griefs_tbl.actioned_status = 'accepted', 1, 0)) AS total_griefs,
    COUNT(all_griefs_tbl.actioned_status ) AS total_submitted,
    all_griefs_tbl.actioned_status, 
    all_griefs_tbl.game 
FROM 
    all_griefs_tbl 
RIGHT JOIN 
    calendar ON ( DATE(all_griefs_tbl.actioned_date ) = calendar.datefield ) 
WHERE 
    calendar.datefield BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -12 MONTH)  AND CURDATE() 
GROUP BY year( calendar.datefield ) DESC , 
    month( calendar.datefield ) DESC
```

**EDIT:** This is a bit unorthodox, but it would (most likely) give you what you're after:

```
SELECT
    month(date_add(curdate(), interval seq.mm months)),
    year(date_add(curdate(), interval seq.mm months)),
    (SELECT count(1)
       FROM all_griefs_tbl
      WHERE actioned_status = 'accepted'
        AND month(action_date) = month(date_add(curdate(), interval seq.mm months))
        AND year(action_date) = year(date_add(curdate(), interval seq.mm months))) as total_griefs
    (SELECT count(1)
       FROM all_griefs_tbl
        AND month(date) = month(date_add(curdate(), interval seq.mm months))
        AND year(date) = year(date_add(curdate(), interval seq.mm months))) as submitted_griefs
FROM
    (SELECT -12 as mm UNION SELECT -11  as mmUNION SELECT -10  as mmUNION SELECT -9  as mm
     UNION SELECT -8 as mm UNION SELECT -7  as mm UNION SELECT -6 as mm UNION SELECT -5 as mm
     UNION SELECT -4 as mm UNION SELECT -3 as mm UNION SELECT -2 as mm UNION SELECT -1 as mm) seq
ORDER BY
    mm
```

Comment: This is close, but I realised I missed something out of my original post.  When counting the total submitted I use `RIGHT JOIN calendar ON ( DATE( all_griefs_tbl.date) = calendar.datefield )` instead of `RIGHT JOIN calendar ON ( DATE( all_griefs_tbl.actioned_date ) = calendar.datefield )`

Comment: @eek I updated my answer with another statement to address your comment.

Comment: Its returning "Unknown column 'calendar.datefield' in 'where clause'"  - I have no idea why because to be quite honest I don't really understand your query Aleks :)

Comment: @eek Sorry, missed one place.  I don't have a facility to test this, so you may need to play with it a bit.  As for explanation, it's quite simple: you right join "calendar" table twice - with different aliases - on different fields.  Then wherever you need a value from that field, you check which of the two joined tables you need.

Comment: Thanks Aleks, that is starting to make some sense now. Looking at what you've changed on the WHERE clause, should the joins be using c1 and c2 respectively?

Comment: @eek Yes, you're absolutely correct.  Way too many places to do copy/paste changes.  I've updated my answer again.

Comment: Ok, progress, I'm getting a result now. Instead of a row for every month in the past 12 months I'm getting a single row returned.  Once I can split the results into months then this will be solved.

Comment: @eek I think I am understanding the problem better now.  The dates may be different.  So you can have something submitted in one month and accepted in another.  Let me think about it - and I'll provide another update.

Comment: The calendar table always has rows. I used it so there would be no missing dates if the total griefs were zero. The dates could be different, so as you say some submitted in one month and accepted in another.

Comment: @eek I change my last sql - the method in the new version is a bit unorthodox, but it should (probably) give you what you're after.  As I pointed out before, I don't have a facility to test this.  I assume that `subselects` inside `select` work.

Comment: Please avoid subselects on column list (as in your second query). This has a potential of slowing the query by orders of magnitude.

Comment: @Mchl Yes, normally I would.  In this particular case though there are always only 13 rows returned, so this may not be as bad as a general case.

Comment: @Aleks This works. I had to change a few bits here and there (months to month, action_date to actioned_date) but the syntax was there.  Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION` with the query if the output is the same of the 2 queries.

So add `NULL AS total_griefs,` and `NULL AS total_submitted,` to the queries, so the output matches

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I really cannot test it)

```
SELECT monthname(calendar.datefield) AS date, 
       year(calendar.datefield) as year, 
       calendar.datefield, 
       SUM(CASE all_griefs_tbl.actioned_status 
               WHEN 'accepted' THEN 1 
               ELSE 0 
           END CASE) AS total_griefs,
       COUNT(all_griefs_tbl.actioned_status) AS total_submitted,
       all_griefs_tbl.actioned_status, 
       all_griefs_tbl.game 
FROM all_griefs_tbl RIGHT JOIN calendar 
    ON DATE(all_griefs_tbl.actioned_date) = calendar.datefield 
WHERE calendar.datefield 
    BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -12 MONTH) AND CURDATE() 
GROUP BY year(calendar.datefield) DESC, 
         month(calendar.datefield) DESC
```